# apache camel with karaf properties config

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf, jbossfuse

I wish to place my properties configuration outside of the fuse installation directory and not in the /etc folder.
Is there any configuration file where I can add another path that would enable the config files to be placed outside fuse installation directory?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure it in /bin/setenv using

`export KARAF_ETC  # Karaf etc  folder`